# Using delete inside function

Tags: c++, memory, bad-alloc

I have problem with calling delete inside functions. When I allocate memory using new inside function it seem do work, but deleting formerly allocated memory causes throwing of std::bad_alloc. Is it even possible, or can I only free memory under "a" from inside of main?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int size = 5;

void alloc (int* t, char**& a) {
  t = new int [size];
  a = new char* [size];
  for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
    a[i] = new char [size];
  cout << "allocated\n";
}

void realloc (char**& a) {
  for(int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
    delete [] a[i];
  delete [] a;
  cout << "deleted\n";
  a = new char* [size];
  for (int i = 0; i < size+5; ++i)
    a[i] = new char [size+5];
  cout << "allocated\n";
}
void fillArray (char** a) {
  for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
    for (int j = 0; j < size; ++j) {
      a[i][j] = '.';
    }
  }
}

void printArray (char** a) {
  for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
    for (int j = 0; j < size; ++j) {
      cout << a[i][j];
    }
    cout << endl;
  }
}
int main() {
  int* t;
  char** a;
  alloc(t, a);
  fillArray(a);
  printArray(a);
  size+=5;
  realloc(a);
  fillArray(a);
  printArray(a);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call `delete[]` from anywhere. Your problems are much more prosaic. You just have a defect in your code.

You allocate an array of length `size`. Then you increment `size`. Then you do this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
    delete [] a[i];
```

And because you incremented `size` already, your loop runs off the end of `a`. You need to use the same value for `size` as was used when you allocated the array.

To be quite clear, the following is the flow of execution:

- `size` is assigned to the value `5`.
- `a` is allocated with length `5`.
- `size` is incremented to the value `10`.
- You run a `for` loop from `0` to `size-1`, that is `0` to `9`, and call `delete[] a[i]`.

Clearly the iterations `5` to `9` inclusive are accessing elements of `a` that were not allocated. And that's undefined behaviour, and so on.

You could fix this by passing the new size to the `realloc` function as a parameter. Something like this:

```
void realloc (char**& a, size_t newsize) {
  for(int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
    delete [] a[i];
  delete [] a;

  size = newsize;
  a = new char* [size];
  for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
    a[i] = new char [size];
}
```

Obviously you would not modify `size` outside of this function. You would call the function like this:

```
realloc(a, size+5);
```

Taking it a bit further, you might choose to handle the allocations like this:

```
size_t size = 5;

void alloc(char**& a, size_t newsize) {
  size = newsize;
  a = new char*[size];
  for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
    a[i] = new char[size];
}

void realloc(char**& a, size_t newsize) {
  for(int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
    delete[] a[i];
  delete[] a;
  alloc(a, size+5);
}
```

All that said, and being perfectly frank, your entire program is a disaster in the making. There are many other errors that I've not covered in this answer. Use standard containers like `std::vector` and `std::string`. The standard containers will handle the details of memory allocation, and will do it correctly.

Comment: Thanks, now it works fine. And if may I ask, what's so terrible about my code?

Comment: 1. (Ab)use of globals. 2. Leaking. 3. Use of `int` rather than `size_t`. 4. Use of raw allocation rather than STL containers. 5. Parameter `t` to `alloc` that can serve no purpose. Caller cannot see the value assigned inside `alloc`.

Comment: Why are STL containers so much better than raw allocation? And about global variable and unused t variable, this program was made just as test and I usually do such things so you can forgive me this ones

Comment: The STL containers are known to work. Your code does not work. The STL containers are easy to use and lead to lean and readable code. They have powerful iterators. Code based on inline raw allocation is hard to maintain and liable to contain errors. Your code leaks. The STL containers do not. STL containers are readily composable with other code. Your code lives in its own island, unable to interact with anything else, unless you write it yourself.